# Is there a way to sync click counts between every user with JS?

Tags: javascript, ajax

HTML

```
<a href="#" title="Awesome" class="btn btn-counter multiple-count" 
data-count="0"><span id="random"></span></a>
```

JS

```
$('.btn-counter').on('click', function(event, count) {
 event.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
  count = $this.attr('data-count'),
  active = $this.hasClass('active'),
  multiple = $this.hasClass('multiple-count');
  $.fn.noop = $.noop;
  $this.attr('data-count', ! active || multiple ? ++count : --count  )
  [multiple ? 'noop' : 'toggleClass']('active');



   });
```

I want it to save the count number but not with local storage. I want it to work like facebook's like system. For ex: It starts at '0' then I press and it becomes '1' and I want to sync this with every user that does that into the website without having to log in.

Maybe you guys understand better if I leave you the code within the site:
https://uishades.co/

Comment: maybe loop with ajax checking rating every few seconds?

Comment: This question is too broad. Good answer really depends on what backend you have. If any?

Comment: w/o server support - not possible. With server support you have 2 possibilities:
- periodic ajax calls to fetch the current value and store own clicks; - using websockets to communicate this information. websockets are more 
 close to "real time".

Comment: try this simple closure in console.var count = (function(){var count=1;return function(){return count++}})()

Comment: @ABUdhay i tried that but after refresh the count number disappears

Answer (score 0):

You need to store this count in database table.
Then its fetch or stay sync with ajax in background for every user.
Then if one user hit -> using ajax store db -> its stored.
Same users page ajax sync for change that count and display it.

If other user active then its background sync ajax also check that db count and show it on page. so it will sync for each user